# using the soul package with equations

Tags: equations, environments, soul

I use the soul package to highlight some changes in my documents for review purposes. However I can't get it to work with equations (or other environments for that matter).

Basically I create a command that will highlight with my color:

```
\newcommand{\MA}[1]{{\sethlcolor{cyan}\hl{#1}}}   %highlighting
```

then I want to use it like in the MWE bellow. I know about putting a  `\protect` command before `\begin{equation}` but the problem with that is that I would have to do it manually. Is there a way of protecting the equations from within the `\newcommand` definition.

Additionally, it seems that the protect methodology compiles well but only highlights until the first protected equation and everything after it remains uncolored.

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}      % Colors
\usepackage{soul}        % Highlighting and strikeout

\newcommand{\MA}[1]{{\sethlcolor{cyan}\hl{#1}}}   %highlighting

\begin{document}

This is not highlighted. \MA{But this is.}

\MA{
this equation
\begin{equation}
    a+b=c
\end{equation}
will not work.
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `soul` manual clearly states that math is allowed when it's used with the `$....$` way, but there is no information for `equation`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With lualatex and the new lua-ul package your example looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{luacolor}      % Colors
\usepackage{lua-ul}        % Highlighting and strikeout

\newcommand{\MA}[1]{\highLight[cyan]{#1}}   %highlighting

\begin{document}

This is not highlighted. \MA{But this is.}

\MA{
this equation
\begin{equation}
    a+b=c
\end{equation}
will not work.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried lualatex but since this looks like a perfect solution I will mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtained the same result with the `empheq` package (needless to load `amsmath` in that case):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Colors
\usepackage{soul} % Highlighting and strikeout

\newcommand{\MA}[1]{{\sethlcolor{cyan}\hl{#1}}} %highlighting
\newcommand*\hlbox[1]{%
\colorbox{cyan!30!}{\quad#1\quad}}
\begin{document}

This is not highlighted. \MA{But this is.}

This equation
\begin{empheq}[box =\hlbox ]{gather}
  a+b=c \\
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{empheq}
works with \texttt{empheq}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bernard for presenting the `empheq` package. It might provide useful in the future. However my objective is to be able to highlight a few paragraphs with equations in-between without having to specifically go and change each equation.

Comment: Note that of you use the `overload` option of empheq, you can keep the old sytax, jusr adding the optional argument  – i mean the example code should  simply write as:    `\begin{gather}[box=\hlbox] … \end{gather}`.