# Can't highlight equation with soul package

Tags: equations, highlighting, soul

I cannot highlight an equation by `\hl` from the `soul` package!

Is there no way to highlight an equation?

Comment: Please tell us more about the equation/formula you wish to highlight. In particular, is it an inline equation or a displayed equation?

Comment: any equation that can be inserted in `\begin{equation}.......\end{equation}`

Comment: @InzoBabaria, things will be easier for all of us if you provide code. Even with a „simple“ environment like yours you can mess up. Kindly follow these steps: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137 . Thank you

Comment: See eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/533379/2388

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

[image]

Code (use the package `empheq`):

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{empheq,xcolor}
\newcommand*\mybox[1]{%
    \colorbox{cyan!30}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{empheq}[box=\mybox]{align}
        ax^2+bx+c=0\\
        x=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
    \end{empheq}
    
    \begin{empheq}[box=\mybox]{align*}
        ax^2+bx+c=0\\
        x=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
    \end{empheq}
\end{document}
```